# HTML5 Canvas rendering stroke in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm new and still learning HTML5 canvas and i have some problems encountered while rendering strokes using Internet Explorer.

This is the output in **Internet Explorer 9**.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxahQU6snNDTN0l1LU9xZENqS3c/view?usp=sharing

While in other browsers (Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Opera, Torch) it works perfectly fine.

This is the desired output which works in other browsers.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxahQU6snNDTNXV4OWNmV1ZiU1E/view?usp=sharing

I really have no idea what is causing the problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: Canvas is the new feature, just probably older browsers dont support canvas features well

Comment: by the way, the IE issue i posted has the same issue in Safari :(


and i still have no idea why. Please help !

Comment: Here is the answer to your problem, scroll to the bottom https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/stroke